# Magento product availability

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need some help tracing back a change i made early on when learning Magento.

On the product page i've removed the part that would normally display the availability, either "In Stock" or "Out of Stock".

I've checked the /catalog/product/type/default.phtml and i've not commented this section out, which seems to be the usual way of fixing it.

I seem to recall i changed something in the admin panel but buggered if i can find anything relating to this.

Can anyone advise on tracing the function back? i presumed it should be seen in /catalog/product/view.phtml but i cannot see anything in there for my template or the base template.

Magento version 1.7.0.2

Forever greatful if anyone can help me figure out what i've done!

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you have deleted this line from your `view.phtml` file

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
```

this in turn call this block

`<block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">`

This is responsible for display stock message on product page.

Comment: I couldn't see the wood for the tree's! I had commented out the line in view.phtml. Thank you!